# In node on Windows 10, how can I get a list of all the voices installed?

Tags: node.js, callback, text-to-speech

I've tried using say js with the following code:

```
 let voices = await say.getInstalledVoices((e, v) => {console.log(v)});
  console.log('voices=', voices);
```

Although the console.log in the callback function returns an array of voices, the voices variable returns a null.

I've had a go at wrapping the call in a promise and got a similar result.

Surely there's a simple one line way of getting those voices? I'm happy to use something other than say to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use await for the method.
The method `say.getInstalledVoices` returns void

Just use the following syntax to get a list of the available voices:

```
const say = require('say');

function getVoices() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    say.getInstalledVoices((err, voice) => {
      return resolve(voice)
    })
  })
}
async function usingVoices() {
  const voicesList = await getVoices();
  console.log(voicesList)
}
usingVoices()
```

You can use the following syntax and do whatever you want to in `usingVoices()` method

Comment: Yes, it returns a list of voices, but I need to get that list into a variable to use further along. I think what I'm asking is how to get the value from the callback function into the mainflow of my code.

Comment: I added a bit different syntax. You can use voicesList in the usingVoices()